# TypeError: stateInfo.map is not a function react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[Please help me with this Error [View Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ezke.png)

Please help me with this map error I am using react-native.

```
TypeError: stateInfo.map is not a function react-native
```

I know there are similar questions, but I can't find out why the error happens. The app crashes (as if was some length problem).

What am I doing wrong?

this is component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Dimensions,
  Keyboard,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";
import { Icon, Input, Button } from "react-native-elements";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import * as Animatable from "react-native-animatable";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import "firebase/auth";
import { Picker } from "@react-native-picker/picker";

const Register = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [subSpinner, setSubSpinner] = useState(false);
  const [stateInfo, setStateInfo] = useState({});
  const [districtInfo, setDistrictInfo] = useState({});
  const [selectedstate, setSelectedState] = useState();
  const [selectedStateCode, setSelectedStateCode] = useState();

  const login = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Login");
  };

  const signIn = () => {
    setSubSpinner(true);
    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        setSubSpinner(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => alert(err));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const getstate = data.states.map((state) => ({
          name: state.state_name,
          value: state.state_id,
        }));
        setStateInfo(getstate);
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(stateInfo);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   fetch(
  //     `https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/districts/${stateInfo.state_id}`
  //   )
  //     .then((response) => response.json())
  //     .then((data) => {
  //       data.states.map((state) => setDistrictInfo(state));
  //     });
  // }, []);
  // console.log(districtInfo);

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Image
            style={{ flex: 1, width: null, marginTop: -100 }}
            source={require("../assets/loginBg.jpg")}
          />
        </View>
        <Animatable.Text
          style={styles.titleText}
          animation="fadeInUp"
          delay={100}
        >
          CoBed-India
        </Animatable.Text>
        <View style={styles.container2}>
          <View style={styles.bottomView}>
            <Text style={styles.loginText}>Login</Text>
            <View style={styles.inputView}>
              <Input
                leftIcon={
                  <Icon
                    style={styles.inputIcon}
                    name="person"
                    type="ionicons"
                    color="black"
                    size={24}
                  />
                }
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Email"
                value={email}
                texttransform="uppercase"
                onChangeText={setEmail}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                keyboardType="email-address"
                textContentType="emailAddress"
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputView}>
              <Input
                leftIcon={
                  <Icon
                    style={styles.inputIcon}
                    name="lock"
                    type="ionicons"
                    color="black"
                    size={24}
                  />
                }
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Password"
                value={password}
                onChangeText={setPassword}
                secureTextEntry={true}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                onSubmitEditing={signIn}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.inputView}>
              <Picker
                selectedValue={selectedstate}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => (
                  setSelectedState(itemValue), setSelectedStateCode(itemIndex)
                )}
              >
                {stateInfo.map((state) => (
                  <Picker.Item
                    label={state.name}
                    value={state.value}
                  ></Picker.Item>
                ))}
              </Picker>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} style={styles.loginButton}>
              <Button
                raised
                disabled={!email || !password}
                onPress={signIn}
                style={styles.loginButtonText}
                title="Login"
              />
              {subSpinner ? (
                <ActivityIndicator
                  style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                  invisible
                  size="large"
                  color="#ffab00"
                />
              ) : null}
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.registerText}>
              Don't have an account?
              <Text onPress={login} style={{ color: "#5352ed" }}>
                {" Login"}
              </Text>
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};

export default Register;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container2: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  titleText: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: Dimensions.get("screen").height * 0.1,
    alignSelf: "center",
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 60,
    elevation: 20,
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#333",
  },
  loginText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginTop: 12,
    marginBottom: 14,
  },
  inputIcon: {
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
  },
  inputView: {
    height: 40,
    marginTop: 10,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  bottomView: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    opacity: 0.95,
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    maxWidth: 700,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
    borderTopRightRadius: 30,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },

  loginButton: {
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  loginButtonText: {
    width: 400,
    alignSelf: "center",
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  registerText: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginTop: 12,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  fpTextd: {
    marginTop: 10,
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#9d9d9d",
  },
  fpTexte: {
    marginTop: 10,
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#5352ed",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial `stateInfo` state is an empty object (`{}`) which has no `.map` function.

```
const [stateInfo, setStateInfo] = useState({});
```

Update your initial state to an array (`[]`) so there is a valid `.map` function to call on the initial render.

```
const [stateInfo, setStateInfo] = useState([]);
```

Comment: @GKRam Other than the `useEffect` that updates your `stateInfo` to be an array, is there anything else that is updated the `stateInfo` state?

Comment: no there is nothing that updates a stateInfo iam trying to get all the states th the api and responding districts api for getting states is https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states and api for getting districts is https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/districts/${state_id} in a dropdown in react native can you help me to get this done if a user click on any state the corresponding district must be apper in the dropdown there are two dropdowns one for state and one for districts

Comment: @GKRam Based on the provided snippet I shared what I believe to be the issue and a working solution. If you disagree can you try to create a *running* [Expo snack](https://expo.io/) that accurately reproduces your error and share that here for us to review and live debug in? I tried hitting that endpoint but seems I need to be authenticated, so if you do make a snack you may need to mock this fetch request/response.

Comment: iam on it 10 min

Comment: its working on sandbox but it was not working on my vscode samdbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-sandbox-51s1x?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @GKRam I updated the initial state in your sandbox and the error is removed, but the fetch fails (codesandbox CORS issue and likely because authentication is required). Can you try updating the sandbox with a mock response? (Or even just a valid response so I can mock a fetch in a fork of the sandbox?

Comment: can you please join in my vscode liveshare https://prod.liveshare.vsengsaas.visualstudio.com/join?49B2382B708E918E531BBB57A30CEC56CFE6